# Does testcafe RequestLogger intersect requests initiated from an iframe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Does testcafe RequestLogger intersect requests initiated from an iframe?

I try to mock all requests done for a page using RequestLogger but maybe I am facing the issue that requests initiated by the iframe are not mocked...

Comment: Could you please share a small example illustrating the issue?

Comment: I was thinking this had a simple yes/no answer. If i build an example illustrating this I will probably get the answer, you are right in that regard...

Answer (score 3):

TestCafe intercepts requests from a page regardless of their source. If you have any issues with this functionality, please submit a [bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and add as much information as possible to the template.